# How to make local server treats a subfolder as the root folder?

Tags: php, absolute-path

When I'm developing my own website on my local server, I put its files in a subfolder. For example, the local url looks something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/projects/myownwebsite/
```

After I upload its files onto the server of a web hosting company, they become in the root folder. So the remote url looks something like this:

```
http://www.myownwebsite.com/
```

The problem is, I want to use absolute path in the references of all my pages and files. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<a href="/about-us/">About Us</a>
<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="My Website">
```

Those absolute paths works perfectly on the remote server. But not on my local server, because on my local server, references like `/about-us/` links to `http://127.0.0.1/about-us/`, which cannot find any page.

I want to make absolute paths works on my local server, too, so that I can develop my own website easier. But I cannot simply put all of the files in the root folder on my local server because there are files and folders of other projects.

Is it possible to make local server treats a subfolder (in this case, the folder of my own website) as the root folder?

P.S. The software I'm using for my local server is [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/).

Comment: is there a reason why you want to use only absolute paths? By the way it's always a good practice to construct your urls in php with a root path constant (as done in frameworks). This way, you just have to change this constant in your config..

Comment: @Kaddath Because absolute paths seem to make things easier and cause less problems. And PHP parsing time is also a reason. If I have hundreds of paths need to be constructed, that would delay the response time and make my PHP code messy.

Comment: didn't do this just to contradict, but i always like to check things myself. Did a benchmark for 1000 urls generation. Maximum difference time for variable assignment was 2 milliseconds in favor of paths without the constant (absolutes). pretty unsignificative. But more, when i did it with an `echo`, max difference was 40 milliseconds in favor of relative paths (which are shorter, in my case it was only 2 chars length difference). Relative paths are quicker because shorter to display. By the way never had "problems" with relative paths

Comment: @Kaddath Thanks for the statistics. I will take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are required to change VirtualHost and `conf_files\httpd.conf file.`

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot "${path}/data/localweb/public_html"
ServerName 127.0.0.1
<Directory "${path}/data/localweb/public_html">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Deny from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

On windows: `configuration->Apache. (opens httpd.conf)`

```
DocumentRoot "D:/proot"
(...)
# DocumentRootDirectory 
<Directory "D:\proot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
 (...)
 NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot "D:/proot/"
   ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>`
```

Repalce `D:/proot/ with your path.`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. But I can't find `Configuration` after right clicking on the EasyPHP icon. The version I'm using is Devserver 17.0.

Comment: Check this if it helps you

Comment: Thanks. That helped. What I did is, in ```httpd.conf```, I made it listen to one more port and added a new ```VurtualHost``` which uses that new port and the subfolder, and now it works.